# High performing set like data structure for array of ints for java

Tags: java, performance, scala

I'm looking for a high performing data structure that behaves like a set and where the elements will always be an array of ints. The data structure only needs to fulfill this interface:

```
trait SetX {
  def size:Int
  def add(element:Array[Int])
  def toArray:Array[Array[Int]]
}
```

The set should not contain duplicates and this could be achieved using Arrays.equals(int[] a, int[] a2) - i.e. the values of the arrays can't be the same.

Before creating it I have a rough idea of how many elements there will be but need resizing behaviour in case there are more than initially thought. The elements will always be the same length and I know what that is at the time of creation.

Of course I could use a Java HashSet (wrapping the arrays of course) but this is being used in a tight loop and it is too slow. I've looked at Trove and that works nicely (by using arrays but providing a TObjectHashingStrategy) but I was hoping that since my requirements are so specific there might be a quicker/more efficient way to do this.

Has anyone ever come across this or have an idea how I could accomplish this?

The trait above is Scala but I'm very happy with Java libs or code.

---

I should really say what I am doing. I am basically generating a large number of int arrays in a tight loop and at the end of it I just want to see the unique ones. I never have to remove elements from the set or anything else. Just add lots of int arrays to the set and at the end get out the unique ones.

Comment: Do you need value or reference semantics? That is, if two different arrays with the numbers in the same order are always equal, or if they have to be the same object.

Comment: The interface contract is underspecified. Do you really mean to say that if you call `add()` with a given `Array[Int]` you want to ensure that no other member contains an array with the same integers in the same order?  If you don't care about duplicates, then a `Set` is not the right data structure.  A simple `List` will suffice.

Comment: Yes it's also unclear if he wants a set of sets and thus the array order and duplicates would/should  not matter.

Comment: As follow-up to @JimGarrison 's comment—does that mean you do not need a `contains` method?

Comment: Did you try using Vector instead of implementing this yourself?

Comment: @JimGarrison yes that is what I mean - I've updated the question to say no duplicates

Comment: @0__ I don't need to call the contains method myself however the implementation might very well need one

Comment: How long are your arrays and how do the contained ints look like?

Comment: @maaartinus the arrays will be between 1 and probably max of about 50 in length. The contained ints can be any int in any order

Answer (score 1):

Look at [prefix trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). You can follow tree structure immediately during array generation. At the end of generation you will have an answer, if the generated array already is present in the set. Prefix tree would consume much less memory than an ordinary hash set.

If you are generating arrays and have a not very small chance of their equivalence, I suspect you are only taking numbers from a very limited range. It would simplify prefix tree implementation, too.

I'm sure that proper implementation would be faster than using any set implementation to keep solid arrays.

Downside of this solution is that you need to implement data structure yourself, because it would be integrated with the logic of code deeply.

Answer (score 0):

With out knowing how much data or if you are doing more reads than write:

You should probably try (ie benchmark) the naive case of an array of arrays or array of special wrapped array (ie composite object with cached hashcode of array and the array). Generally on small data sets not much beats looping through an array (e.g. HashMap for an Enum can actually be slower than looping through).

If you have really large amount of data and your willing to make some compromises you might consider a [bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) but it sounded like you don't have much data.

Comment: what is a bloom filter?

Comment: That's what search engines are for ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want high performance then write your own:

Call it ArraySetInt.

Sets are usually either implemented as trees or hashtable.

If you want an array based set, this would slow down adding,  maybe deleting, but will speed up iterating, low memory usage. etc.

First look how ArrayList is implemented.
remove the object and replace it with primitive int.

Then rename the add() to put() and change it to a type of sort by insertion. Use System.arraycopy() to insert. use  Arrays.binsearch() to find the insert position and whether element already exist in one step.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for some classic solution wrapping the array by a class providing faster `equals` and `hashCode`. The `hashCode` can be simply cached and `equals` can make use of it for quickly saying no in case of differing arrays.

I'd avoid `Arrays.hashCode` as it uses a stupid multiplier (31), which might lead to unneeded collisions. For a really fast `equals` you could make use of cryptography and say that two arrays are equals if and only if their [SHA-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) are equal (you'd be the first to find a collision :D).

The [ArrayWrapper](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4971686/published/maaartin/so/ArrayWrapper.java) rather simple and should be faster than using `TObjectHashingStrategy` as it never has to look at the data itself (fewer cache misses) and it has the fastest and best possible `hashCode` and `equals`.

You could also look for some [CompactHashSet](https://www.google.com/search?q=CompactHashSet+java) implementation as it can be faster due to better memory locality.